# IntegrityError at /posts/12/new-comment/ NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.author_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Well i am adding commenting system in my project but got an integrity error. I dont know how to solve this. I have already asked this question one time but now one answer it. But now i am asking it again i hope someone will answer it with brief detail. I shall be very thankful to you.

view.py

```
class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    redirect_field_name='posts/post_detail.html' 
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "posts/snippets/comment_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):

    
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/12/new-comment/

Django Version: 3.0.3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'profiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.author_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\grapPub\grabpublic\posts\views.py", line 74, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 125, in form_valid
    self.object = form.save()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 459, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 745, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 782, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 924, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1384, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /posts/12/new-comment/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: posts_comment.author_id
```

If more detail is require than tell me. I will update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the logged in user as author:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    redirect_field_name='posts/post_detail.html' 
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "posts/snippets/comment_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

There is also an error in the [**`.get_absolute_url(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) of the `Comment` class, since you are using the detail page of the post, the `pk` parameter should be the id of the `post` object, so you can use `self.post_id`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post_id})
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: It is working but it is redirecting me on other posts. Not on that post on which i am commenting.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: yes, it should be `self.post_id` in the `get_absolute_url`, see edit.

Comment: I have just changed `author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to `author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`  and when i try again to comment than it showing an error : **ValueError at /posts/12/new-comment/

Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: testuser>>": "Comment.author" must be a "UserProfile" instance.**

Comment: @FlashMaddy: well then likely your user model is `UserProfile`. So in that case, it does not make much sense to have a `User` model anymore. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: one normally *either* makes a custom user model, or one uses an extra `UserProfile` model (but in that case you normally do not make it the user model).

Comment: Thank you I just fixed it out :D

Comment: Just one more thing i am wanting to ask related to this problem, I want to ask that how can profile picture of user who comment below that post, write now i am trying with `<img src="{{comment.author.userprofile.avatar.url}}" />` and it is showing me current login user profile.

Comment: @FlashMaddy: if the user has commented, then that is the avatar. Did you try commenting with *another* user?

Comment: I just tried with other user and it's showing right data. Sorry for taking your too much time but really thank you so much again!

Comment: I have ask new question and you can see if you can answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379751/how-to-solve-403-forbidden-error-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You should set form data before it is validated and you should also set `author` ID there

```py
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  redirect_field_name='posts/post_detail.html' 
  model = Comment
  form_class = CommentForm
  template_name = "posts/snippets/comment_form.html"

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['post']= self.kwargs['pk']
    kwargs['author']= self.request.user.id
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Yeah it fix not the integrity error but it is redirecting me on other posts. Not redirecting me on the post where i am commenting

Comment: I have ask new question and you can see if you can answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379751/how-to-solve-403-forbidden-error-in-django)